# get an iframe's "src" value in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

I have an iframe on my page, where on click (a menu) will update the iframe with a new URL depending on what menuitem they select.

I do that by calling javascript function on 'onclick' passing the URL from the menu :

```
   function frameclick(pageurl)
     {
            $("#iFrame1").attr('src', pageurl);         
     }
```

What i would like to do whenever they press a menuitem is to store what iframe is loaded, because i have another button (select page language) and when they press that i want to reload the page but pass on the iframe-url that is currently displayed as a variable in the site url.

Since PHP is serverside and JS is clientside, i cannot do ex. "$current_iframe_url = pageurl" - which would have enabled me to pass it on as a variable on refresh.

You know how i could get around this ?

That works fine.

What i want to do now, is to whenever they click a menuitem i want to store that URL

Comment: There are good reasons why frames are unpopular, and you just found one. Just saying.

Comment: Boann, i understand but what would be the alternative if you want a page that doesnt completely reload on most of the action going on ( menu & show a result page).

Comment: Get it working without frames first. Then to avoid a complete reload, get the onclick handler of the menu links to use a bit of [script/AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to replace the content of the inner area, combined with [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to update the URL displayed in the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on every click create a hidden field  save the value of url in a hidden field then only change the url. then after that you can simple submit the form using ajax .
or when ever user clicks call an ajax function so that u can copy the url in database or session what ever you like.
sample

```
function frameclick(pageurl)
 {
   $.post("server.php", { url: pageurl } );
   $("#iFrame1").attr('src', pageurl);         
 }
your php  server.php should do something like this


if(isset($_POST['url']){
//INSERT IN TO DB
}
```

Comment: lets say when i do the refresh page for language-select ( note page is not refreshed per menuitem only iFrame ) how could i retrieve that value ? 
in my onchange event for the language-select button, im looking at how to do pass a <"index.php?iframeurl=<?PHP echo $current_page_url ?"> should i then use GET or something ? note: noob alert so hope you bear over with me.

Comment: when ever frameclick function is called you have to save the url using ajax .

Comment: just edited my response (ENTER posts the comment :/ ) - but how would the ajax part be looking ?

Comment: look at the code that i have given as sample $.post("server.php", { url: pageurl } );

Comment: yes thanks, i almost get the idea. but how to access that value ? should i use $_SESSION['url'] or ?

Comment: every time user clicks u should send the data to server and store some where persistent .actually for the javascript ajax part my code will work .but server logic you have to do.

Comment: Any way i can store it in the session - i dont have a database attached

Comment: sorry after abit of investigation here i understand what you meant by your first answer, very precise actually :) thanks alot !!

Answer (score 0):

Following fiddle used to get its URL, http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/FUUz9/1/

Hope this also helpful,

```
$('iframe').bind('mouseover', function(){
    var iframeID = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).contents().find('html').unbind(); 
    $(this).contents().find('html').bind('click', function(){
        alert(iframeID);  
    });
})
```

; ​

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but im not quite sure how this stores the URL for the iframe ?