# javascript post to .php file one server does not work - manual entry of URL in browser to same .php works

Tags: php, javascript

i had some issues with understanding how to get javascript (client) variables transferred so they were acessible from php (serverside) as session : [get an iframe's "src" value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099007/get-an-iframes-src-value-in-php#comment17803278_13099007)

Now im in a situation where i use firebug to try to debug whats going on, but it just doesnt make sense :

i have this function to update an iframe and i want to pass on the page that that iframe is displaying :

```
function frameclick(pageurl)
 {
        $.post("session_write.php?",
    {
            frameurl : pageurl             
    }

    $("#iFrame1").attr('src', pageurl);
    console.log  ('<?php echo "logout:".$langpath.$_SESSION['frameurl'];?>');
 }
```

pageurl is ex. "/lang/en/new.htm" - and if i inspect it with firebug i also can see it says that it passes it correctly ( also with conversion of /).

my script serverside that its posted to is like this :

```
#session_write.php
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_GET['frameurl']);
if (isset($_GET['frameurl'])) 
{
$_SESSION['frameurl'] = $_GET['frameurl'];
print_r($_SESSION);
}
?>
```

Posting to that php script on the server will fail via the javascropt - $_SESSION['frameurl'] will be '', but if i ex. do it manually like this :
(http):

```
//localhost/phpmenu/session_write.php?frameurl=lang%2Fen%2Fnew.htm
```

then it will be correctly set in the $_SESSION["frameurl"] variable.

I simply cannot understand whats different between doing the javascript post and doing it manually in the browser and why its causing me this problem ?

anyone with an idea ? thanks

Comment: Just from reading your javascript - your `$.post` isn't closed off either.  But read the answers below for a solution, your PHP is accessing the `GET` variable, your javascript is `POST`ing it.  In PHP you can change `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` so it works with both GET and POST, but that isn't suggested, so change it to `$_POST` so it works with your JS, but you won't be able to test it by typing in the URL

Comment: thanks alot. should have asked earlier been pulling my hair on this one for hours on end :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.post`, which executes a POST request, but when you type in the URL in the address bar, that is a GET request.

`$_GET` retrieves any params passed through GET, while `$_POST` retrieves any params passed through POST. So if you use `.post` with Javascript but try to retrieve with `$_GET` in PHP, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Deleted snark. Stack overflow is not the place for snark.

Comment: I feel so stupid now :( just tried to change my POST to GET and it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you POST variables to a PHP file, `$_GET` is not set. Use `$_POST['frameurl']` instead. Also, it looks like you're missing a close paren in `frameclick` to end the `post` call.

Comment: the closed paranthese is a copy/paste mistake. but thanks alot also

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data via a 
    `POST`  request and retrieving for all the GET requests. Use `$_POST` instead. You may also be interested in `$_REQUEST`